# How to create Transparent Activity With Picture in Android?

Tags: android, xml, transparent

I want to create a *transparent* `Activity` that load when we open the application on top of another `Activity` exactly like [this](http://postimg.org/image/ovaqw14n5/).

I want that picture to be clicked and then it open the browser to open the link integrated with this image

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i think this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(WelcomeScreenActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme); WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    WMLP.x = 0;   
    WMLP.y = 0;  
    WMLP.dimAmount = 0.0f;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
    dialog.show();          this in code                                     <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_white</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style> add this in style.xml

Comment: @kumar Please where do I add the picture and the link?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/videobackground"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```